# How to convert json file to Deno doc website

Tags: typescript, documentation, deno, typedoc

I have created a JSON format file for a particular module in my Deno project using "deno doc --Json > sample.json". This creates a sample.json file of the module. Then I cloned and setup the doc_website in my local.

But I am confused how to use sample.json file in doc_website. I am stuck with where to add this file in doc_wesite folder structure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't completely understand your question, but there is now a new method to add modules to Deno! Just go to https://deno.land/x#add and click the "Add a module" button and it should ask you a couple of questions. After that, you should be able to search for your module at [the Deno Third-Party modules index](https://deno.land/x) and it should *magically appear!* If it doesn't appear in the search, do CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + R to clear the cache of the docs and it should work now :) If you have any further questions or troubles, just reply!

Edit: Also remember to [read the Deno Contributing Style Guide](https://deno.land/manual/contributing/style_guide)!